# Package changes horizontal pipe to horizontal for chapter formatting

Tags: formatting, packages, chapters

I need to change the style of my chapters to a [different one](http://i1.wp.com/texblog.org/Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/titlesec_style.png). I found a package which would do that, and it works nicely.

However, my code before the edit was like this:

```
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{<}\def\UrlRight{>} \urlstyle{tt}}
```

After the edit, I made it into this:

```
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{<}\def\UrlRight{>} \urlstyle{tt}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

Thank worked nicely, however the text wasn't in the straight lines, looks like on the picture below.

[image: Text after the first edit]

However, I am aware of double fontenc package, so I removed that one, code looking like this:

```
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{<}\def\UrlRight{>} \urlstyle{tt}}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

Howver that make a strange thing. Although my text lines were straight, the pipe in the chapter name it made horizontal, looks like this:

[image: Text after the second edit, removing the duble package]

Anyone would know how to solve this issue? Thank you

EDIT: Adding more of the code

```
\documentclass[cover]{fitthesis} % odevzdani do wisu 
%      \documentclass[english]{fitthesis}

% zde zvolime kodovani, ve kterem je napsan text prace
% "latin2" pro iso8859-2 nebo "cp1250" pro windows-1250, "utf8" pro "utf-8"
%\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{<}\def\UrlRight{>} \urlstyle{tt}}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\ifWis
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined % nejedeme pod pdflatexem
\else
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,hyperindex,plainpages=false,pdftex]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[all]{nowidow}
  \definecolor{links}{rgb}{0.4,0.5,0}
  \definecolor{anchors}{rgb}{1,0,0}
  \def\AnchorColor{anchors}
  \def\LinkColor{links}
  \def\pdfBorderAttrs{/Border [0 0 0] }  % bez okrajů kolem odkazů
  \pdfcompresslevel=9
\fi
\fi

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents

  \listoffigures
  % \listoftables 
  \input{obsah} % viz. obsah.tex

\ifczech
  \bibliographystyle{czechiso}
\else 
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
%  \bibliographystyle{alpha}
\fi
  \begin{flushleft}
  \bibliography{literatura} % viz. literatura.bib
  \end{flushleft}
  \appendix

  \input{prilohy} % viz. prilohy.tex
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you add a complete minimale cod

Comment: the option `IL2` of `fontenc` is it necessary

Comment: without IL2 option I get those not straight lines. And I'll add the code

Comment: you can repalce `|` in chapter style by `\rule[-.2em]{1pt}{1em}` and you can adjust it by changing 1em to .9em or .8em

Comment: the option IL2 of fontenc will cause this every time you type `|` soo be careful, (you shoud find a solution)

Comment: Use `\textbar` and not `|`. But are you *really* sure you need `IL2`? You seem to be using an outdated template: for instance, the test `\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined` will always return false on current TeX distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `\textbar` for the “pipe” in text mode (`|` is good in math mode).

<sub>You seem to be using a very old template and I don't think you should be loading the `IL2` package. The test `\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined` is a clear sign of this; note that on current TeX distributions (less than five year old or so), the test will always return false.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dirty workaround. Let me know if you run into trouble using this (I hope not).

[image]

```
\documentclass[cover]{fitthesis} % odevzdani do wisu 
%      \documentclass[english]{fitthesis}

% zde zvolime kodovani, ve kterem je napsan text prace
% "latin2" pro iso8859-2 nebo "cp1250" pro windows-1250, "utf8" pro "utf-8"
%\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}

\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{<}\def\UrlRight{>} \urlstyle{tt}}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\usepackage[T1, IL2]{fontenc}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{$|$}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}



\ifWis
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined % nejedeme pod pdflatexem
\else
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,hyperindex,plainpages=false,pdftex]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[all]{nowidow}
  \definecolor{links}{rgb}{0.4,0.5,0}
  \definecolor{anchors}{rgb}{1,0,0}
  \def\AnchorColor{anchors}
  \def\LinkColor{links}
  \def\pdfBorderAttrs{/Border [0 0 0] }  % bez okrajů kolem odkazů
  \pdfcompresslevel=9
\fi
\fi

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000

\begin{document}

\chapter{\'Uvod}
\end{document}
```